# pandas pivot_table column name should not be present and how to order a text column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm learning pandas.

I have created this test dataframe:

```
dfdict = {'product':['ruler', 'pencil', 'case', 'rubber'],'sold':[4,23,0,14],'Quarter':['Q1/22','Q2/23','Q3/22','Q1/23']}
dftest=pd.DataFrame(dfdict)
dftemp=dftest.pivot_table(index=['product'],columns=['Quarter'],values=['sold'],aggfunc=sum,fill_value=0)
print(f"{dftemp}")
```

which produces:

```
         sold
Quarter Q1/22 Q1/23 Q2/23 Q3/22
product
case        0     0     0     0
pencil      0     0    23     0
rubber      0    14     0     0
ruler       4     0     0     0
```

Two points I need help with:

1. How do I remove only the `sold` column name? I don't want it there as when I write it to a csv each `Quarter` column has a "sold" name above it.
2. How can I order the `Quarter` columns in date order, right now they are text. What's the best way? Is it to somehow convert them into a date and then order them and write it out in the same style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert column `Quarter` to quarters, so `pivot_table` sorting correct ouput, for remove `MultiIndex` in columns for `sold` change one element lists like `[sold]` to `sold`:

```
dftest['Quarter'] = pd.PeriodIndex(dftest['Quarter'].str[-2:] +
                                   dftest['Quarter'].str[:2], freq='Q')

dftemp=dftest.pivot_table(index='product',
                          columns='Quarter', 
                          values='sold',
                          aggfunc=sum,
                          fill_value=0)
print(f"{dftemp}")
Quarter  2022Q1  2022Q3  2023Q1  2023Q2
product                                
case          0       0       0       0
pencil        0       0       0      23
rubber        0       0      14       0
ruler         4       0       0       0
```

Last if need original or another formating use `rename` with `strftime`:

```
dftemp = dftemp.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strftime('Q%q/%y'))
print(f"{dftemp}")
Quarter  Q1/22  Q3/22  Q1/23  Q2/23
product                            
case         0      0      0      0
pencil       0      0      0     23
rubber       0      0     14      0
ruler        4      0      0      0
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't uses lists as arguments of [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and then [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with a custom key (for example using [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) or a [`PeriodIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.html)):

```
out = (dftest
       .pivot_table(index='product', columns='Quarter', values='sold',
                    aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0)
       .sort_index(axis=1, key=lambda x: x.str.replace(r'(Q\d)/(\d+)', r'\2-\1', regex=True))
      )
```

Or:

```
out = (dftest
       .pivot_table(index='product', columns='Quarter', values='sold',
                    aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0)
       .sort_index(axis=1, key=lambda x: pd.PeriodIndex(x.str.replace(r'(Q\d)/(\d+)', r'\2-\1', regex=True), freq='Q'))
      )
```

Output:

```
Quarter  Q1/22  Q3/22  Q1/23  Q2/23
product                            
case         0      0      0      0
pencil       0      0      0     23
rubber       0      0     14      0
ruler        4      0      0      0
```